# NetBeans / JavaFX build: Debian Installed-Size

Tags: java, netbeans, debian, javafx-2, ubuntu-10.04

Whenever I build a .deb package using NetBeans 7.2 and then install it, I get the following message:

```
The package is of bad quality

The installation of a package which violates the quality standards isn't allowed.
This could cause serious problems on your computer.  Please contact the person or
organisation who provided this package file and include the details beneath.

Details V
The package doesn't provide a valid Installed-Size control field.  See Debian Policy 5.6.20

[OK]  [Ignore and install]
```

Clicking `[Ignore and install]` button works fine, app installs, runs/works great.  Guess I just need to set the `Installed-Size` setting via NetBeans somehow.  Surprised that it doesn't just do this automatically when building the package for me.  (I am building for x86/32-bit, Ubuntu 10.04 LTS--w/latest updates, a Java JDK 7 / JavaFX 2.2 application, if it matters.)

I am using the following target in my build.xml:

```
<target name="-post-jfx-deploy">
    <fx:deploy width="${javafx.run.width}" height="${javafx.run.height}"
               nativeBundles="all"
               outdir="${basedir}/${dist.dir}" outfile="${application.title}">
        <fx:application name="${application.title}"
                        mainClass="${javafx.main.class}"/>
        <fx:resources>
            <fx:fileset dir="${basedir}/${dist.dir}" includes="*.jar"/>
        </fx:resources>
        <fx:info title="${application.title}" vendor="${application.vendor}"/>
    </fx:deploy>
</target>
```

Can anyone tell me what settings I need to change/set in NetBeans (7.2) in order to fix this (that is, how to set the Installed-Size control field when building, using NetBeans)?  I have hunted and hunted, assuming someone has had this issue before me, but no luck.

Comment: Per JavaFX team member Igor, I've submitted a bug on this: http://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-25486 (Feel free to vote on it there, if you're having this issue as well!)

Here is the Oracle JavaFX forum thread where he recommended reporting this as a bug: https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=2447475